# So Close: How to get this SSH login working (.bashrc)

Tags: ssh, bashrc

Objective: SSH login ( + eliminate warning message) / run 2 commands / stay logged in:

EDIT: Oops, I made a mistake (see below):

This code does ~95% of what I wanted to do

```
# .bashrc
# Run two commands and stay logged in to new server.
alias gr='ssh -t -p 5xx4x root@9x.1xx.51.00 2> /dev/null "cd /var; ls; /bin/bash -i"'
```

Now, after successful login / verify user logged in =

> root     pts/0        2011-01-30 22:09

Try to 'logout' =

> bash: logout: not login shell: use
>   `exit'

I seem to have full root access **w/o** being logged into the shell? (The " /bin/bash -i " was added to 'Stay logged in' but doesn't work quite as expected)
FYI: The question is *"How to get this SSH login working"* & it is mostly solved, sorry I made a mess...

...

..

.

Original Question Here:

```
# .bashrc
# Run two commands and stay logged in to new server.
alias gr='ssh -t -p 5xx4x root@9x.1xx.51.00 "cd /var; ls; /bin/bash -i"'

# (hack) Hide "map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!"  message.
alias gr='ssh -p 5xx4x root@9x.1xx.51.00 2> /dev/null'
```

Both examples 'work' as shown; When I try to add the ' 2> /dev/null ' to the first example, then the whole thing breaks.

- I'm out of time trying to solve the
  warning message other ways, so **is it
  possible** to combine both examples to
  make example #1 work w/o the warning
  message?

Thank you.

ps. If you also know a proper way to kill the login warning message, please do tell (the 'standard' *"edit host file"* advice isn't working for me)

Comment: Fix the warning message. The warning message tells you the exact line in `authorized_keys` you should delete so that it disappears (given that you acknowledged the warning, and the server key really changed).

Comment: How are you adding the redirection to the first command and in what way does it break?

Comment: @Juliano Not that type of warning; This one is related to the hostname/ IP & I'm using a VPS (no control over the true server root), so far unable to fix... "Check dns" is off in ssh config. @Dennis Will update ASAP.

Comment: @Dennis Good point, thanks. I was online 'too long' and had made an error. My original post is edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `bash: logout: not login shell: use 'exit'` message because you started an interactive non-login shell. Try `bash -l` or `bash -il` instead.